# The window is set to not active, the text box window can not get the focus and can not enter text

Tags: c#, wpf, windows

I use the following code to set my WPF window not to get focus, but the setup is complete, this window can not enter text in the text box, and how to make this window neither get focus, but also can in which enter text in the text box?

```
#region set window no focus
public const int GWL_EXSTYLE = -20;
public const int WS_EX_NOACTIVATE = 0x8000000;
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern int SetWindowLong(IntPtr window, int index, int value);
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern int GetWindowLong(IntPtr window, int index);
/// <summary>
/// set window no focus
/// </summary>
/// <param name="hwnd"></param>
public static void SetWindowNoFocus(IntPtr hwnd)
{
    SetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_EXSTYLE, GetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_EXSTYLE) | WS_EX_NOACTIVATE );
}
#endregion set window no focus
```

Comment: You don't want window to be activated, but you need to activate window, if you want to process keyboard events.

Comment: Please post the *relevant* code. Are you asking how the user can type text in a textbox that doesn't have the focus (a contradiction)? Or how can you programmatically change the text of a TextBox?

Comment: Your question does not make sense. You want your window to not get any input but you wonder why it does not get input? You need to decide what you want. Do you want input?

Comment: Thanks all,I don't want window to be activated, but I need to allow user to input text to the TextBox which is in this window.Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

```
    [DllImport("USER32.DLL", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    public static extern IntPtr FindWindow(String lpClassName, String lpWindowName);

    [DllImport("USER32.DLL")]
    public static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

    public static void BringToFront(string title)
    {
        // Get a handle to the Calculator application.
        IntPtr handle = FindWindow(null, title);

        // Verify that Calculator is a running process.
        if (handle == IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            return;
        }

        // Make Calculator the foreground application
        SetForegroundWindow(handle);
    }
```